# How to set custom editor color for attribute in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper

I was wondering if it was possible to set a custom color for attributes inside of Visual Studio, natively or using ReSharper.

**Ideally, I would love to be able to highlight specific attributes with specific colors but I have been unable to find a solution for this.**

[image: Perfect Situation]

Using ReSharper, I can change their colors using `ReSharper Class Identifier` but that changes the colors for all class references. I've tried using `user keywords` in a `usertype.dat` file. I've tried using custom task list tokens but those weren't helping either.

Answer (score 2):

**Attribute** word is a little confusing. Although the generic term is **Attribute**, they are more or less **User defined classes**. 
 
Try this: 
Tools => Options => Environment => Fonts and Colors => Text Editor => User Types - Classes.
Change foreground color.

Comment: OP is Asking about Attributes, not all classes, and possibly about overriding the default coloring on a per-attribute basis.